# Adding elements to one or more static lists with static factory-style constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, static, constructor, arraylist

I want to maintain a list of buttons which I place in a GUI in a grid-like layout.

I have been using the javax.swing.JButton, and have made my own subclass of it, called ColoredButton.

I want them stored in a static arraylist, so that i can perform the same function on all of them (setting the color). This wasn't too difficult.

NOW I am trying to add the extra feature of separating them out into 3 different types when I initialize them: Corner, Edge, and Center buttons. The thing is, whenever I construct one of these 3 types, I want to add it to the ColoredButton static arraylist, as well as the static arraylist for its specific subtype.

I had seen that using "this" as a parameter to add the current item to the list doesnt work (returns a null pointer because "this" is incomplete).

So instead I have been using factory-style construction.
Here is my superclass ColoredButton and one of its derived classes.

```
public class ColoredButton extends JButton{
    private static ArrayList <ColoredButton> all;

    protected static void addToColored(ColoredButton B){
        all.add(B);
    }

    public static ColoredButton newColoredButton(){
        ColoredButton B = new ColoredButton();
        ColoredButton.all.add(B);
        return B;
    }

    public static void setAll(Color C){
        for(ColoredButton B: ColoredButton.all)
            B.setBackground(C);
    }
}

public class EdgeButton extends ColoredButton {
    private static ArrayList <EdgeButton> all;

    public static EdgeButton newEdgeButton(){
        EdgeButton B = new EdgeButton();
        EdgeButton.all.add(B);
        addToColored(B);
        return B;
    }

    public static void setAll(Color C){
        for(EdgeButton B: EdgeButton.all)
            B.setBackground(C);
    }
}
```

Now when I try to do something like this:

```
EdgeButton B1 = EdgeButton.newEdgeButton();
```

I get a NullPointerException. The compiler says that the error originated in this line:

```
EdgeButton.all.add(B);
```

So where am I going wrong? Why am I getting a null ptr exception?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized your list. So, it is still `null` while you access it.

Change:

```
private static ArrayList <EdgeButton> all;
```

to:

```
private static List<EdgeButton> all = new ArrayList<EdgeButton>();
```

in both your your classes. Note, you should use *interfaces* for reference types.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm fairly new to Java and forgot that little detail. So in Java, Interfaces can store static fields? & would i just say that ColoredButton extends JButton and EdgeButton extends ColoredButton?